# Listar impressoras na rede com PHP

Tags: php, web-service, linux, aplicação-web, impressão

Necessito que todas as impressoras na rede sejam listadas na minha aplicação para  fins de configuração da mesma, mas até então estou encontrando dificuldades para fazer. Em principio estou utilizando o Windows no servidor da aplicação, mas penso em utilizar o Linux com o passar do tempo. Fiz testes com o php_printer.dll (somente Windows), mas não consegui fazer listar as impressoras que estão compartilhadas na rede.

Para impressão utilizo o componente https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php mas infelizmente com ele também não consegui fazer listar quais impressoras estão na rede. O meu cliente já tem as impressoras instaladas da marca Epson com uma aplicação antiga, onde estamos fazendo um novo sistema para substituir o antigo.

Em principio as impressoras devem ser listadas em uma listagem (componente select/option - HTML) de forma dinâmica (preferencialmente, a fim de detectar qualquer alteração na rede/nas impressoras) a cada vez que se entra na tela referente para as devias configurações. Cada impressora pertence a um setor e nesta tela é configurada cada impressora a cada setor. Não é pré-requisito que seja Windows o servidor, pode ser Linux, por exemplo, onde no caso sob Linux até então não encontrei nada a respeito de listagem das impressoras instaladas mesmo que seja local.

**Obs:**
O motivo da escolha do Windows foi ao fato de antes ter buscado em Linux e não ter encontrado nenhuma solução. Em Linux é possível listas as impressoras instaladas no servidor localmente ou em rede?

Comment: Não sei quais informações são necessárias, se o servidor é windows não seria mais fácil obter as informações via powershell ou wmi e guardar em um banco de dados 'temporario' que o php acessaria?

Comment: Lembrando, somente impressoras "disponíveis" ao S.O. onde o PHP está sendo executado que podem ser listadas dessa forma.

Comment: Sim, existe as devidas configurações no S.O para que o mesmo acesse as impressoras, e depois foi feito teste com "página de teste" do próprio S.O. (no caso Windows, mas estou disposto a Linux, caso encontre a solução no mesmo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A impressora só vai aparecer se ela estiver configurada no servidor, desconheço descoberta de impressoras usando php sozinho(talvez algum comando do sistema operacional).

Como você está utilizando windows, vou considerar este ambiente, em linux a solução é parecida.

## Utilizando a extensão php_printer :

A extensão php_printer é o meio padrão para se obter as impressoras conectadas ao servidor.  Porém ela não vai identificar as impressoras de rede que não estejam configuradas no servidor pois não permite descoberta.

Eu fiz a instalação uma vez seguinte este tutorial (em inglês) :

http://basic-programming-tips.blogspot.ch/2013/07/php-phpprinterdll-installation-and.html

Vá até o diretório do arquivo php.ini (ex. C:/PHP5/php.ini)

1. Abra o arquivo
2. Procure por ;extension=php_printer.dll
3. Remova o ";"
4. Reinicie o servidor.

Caso a configuração acima não funcione, você pode tentar o PHP-Printer (em inglês) https://github.com/jiminald/PHP-Printer 
Porém aparentemente esta extensão foi descontinuada (nem mesmo a documentação está disponível: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=printer&scope=quickref).

## Obtendo impressoras sem a extensão, usando apenas linha de comando no windows:

Quando o PHP por sí só não consegue, podemos utilizar alguma interface de linha de comando, seja um script java ou python ou até mesmo um script php rodando com um php mais antigo. 
A técnica consiste em utilizar uma linha de comando e tratar a string do resultado.

```
<?php
//Função para tratar o retorno 
function getPrinterProperty($key){
    $str = shell_exec('wmic printer get '.$key.' /value');

    $keyname = "$key=";
    $validValues = [];
    $fragments = explode(PHP_EOL,$str);
    foreach($fragments as $fragment){
        if($fragment == ""){
            continue;
        }
        if (preg_match('/('.$keyname.')/i', $fragment)) {
            array_push($validValues,str_replace($keyname,"",$fragment));
        }
    }
    return $validValues;
}
//Esplanação dos commandos:
// wmic /node:SERVER1 printer list status // Lista status das impressoras de um servidor remoto
// wmic printer list status // Lista status das impressoras  do servidor local
// wmic printer get // Obtem todas as propriedades da impressoa
// wmic printer get <propriedade> /value //Lista uma propriedade no formato chave=valor do servidor remoto
// wmic printer get <propriedade> /value //Lista uma propriedade no formato chave=valor do servidor local

//Obtém algumas propriedades, nesse caso vou pegar só algumas
$Name = getPrinterProperty("Name");
$Description =  getPrinterProperty("Description");
$Network = getPrinterProperty("Network");
$Local = getPrinterProperty("Local");
$PortName = getPrinterProperty("PortName");
$Default = getPrinterProperty("Default");
$Comment = getPrinterProperty("Comment");

$Printers = [];
foreach($Name as $i => $n){
    $Printers[$i] = (object)[
        "name" => $n,
        "description" => $Description[$i],
        "Portname" => $PortName[$i],
        "isDefault" =>($Default[$i] == "TRUE")? true : false,
        "isNetwork" => ($Network[$i] == "TRUE")? true : false,
        "isLocal" =>($Local[$i] == "TRUE")? true : false,
        "Comment" => $Comment[$i],
    ];
}

var_dump($Printers);
```

O retorno esperado é algo assim:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(29) "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Portname"]=>
    string(11) "PORTPROMPT:"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isNetwork"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isLocal"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(22) "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Portname"]=>
    string(11) "PORTPROMPT:"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isNetwork"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isLocal"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(32) "HPC4C962 (HP Officejet Pro 8600)"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Portname"]=>
    string(45) "WSD-5277c4df-fd03-46fb-a957-1d8a0fd65b01.003c"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["isNetwork"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isLocal"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(30) "This is a web services printer"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(29) "HP Officejet Pro L7600 Series"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Portname"]=>
    string(12) "192.168.1.22"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isNetwork"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isLocal"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(24) "Foxit Reader PDF Printer"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Portname"]=>
    string(13) "FOXIT_Reader:"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isNetwork"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isLocal"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Fax"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Portname"]=>
    string(7) "SHRFAX:"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isNetwork"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isLocal"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [6]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(26) "Enviar para o OneNote 2013"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Portname"]=>
    string(4) "nul:"
    ["isDefault"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isNetwork"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["isLocal"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["Comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

## Como solicitar uma impressão sem plugin (windows)?

Você pode instalar algum aplicativo que permita executar via linha de comando, como o [Foxit Reader](https://help.foxitsoftware.com/?action=list&cate_id=92), e adicioná-lo à variável de ambiente PATH, para que possa executar o comando de qualquer lugar. Então pode-se utilizar o código ali em cima e executar desta forma:

```
<?php 

shell_exec('FoxitReader /t C:/Temp/file.txt "'.$Printers[0]->name.'"');
```

Comment: Agradeço pela sua resposta. Vou fazer os testes. Você tinha mencionado  que em Linux a solução é parecida. O que em especifico teria que ser alterado caso fosse em Linux, pois o motivo da escolha do Windows foi ao fato de antes ter buscado em Linux e não ter encontrado nenhuma solução.

Comment: Em Linux, é possível listas as impressoras instaladas no servidor localmente ou em rede?

Comment: Quando disse que é parecido, é por conta da técnica, você utiliza um comando do sistema operacional e trata ele no php.
Os comandos que permitem encontrar uma impressora no linux é o lpstat -d -p, porém estou sem nenhuma máquina para testar a saída e montar um script.
Para descobrir impressoras na rede não instaladas você ainda pode usar o nmap -A no linux porém precisa filtrar pois ele irá detectar todos os dispositivos visíveis na rede.