# Ajuda com php_printer.dll

Tags: php, impressora

Uso PHP 5.5.12 e baixei a versão da dll compativel e quando abre a página não acontece nada e tambem não aparece nenhum erro.
Reiniciei o Wamp e adicionei as linhas correspondentes no php.ini

php.ini

```
 printer.default_printer=PHP_INI_ALL
 extension=php_printer.dll
```

imprime_cupom.php

```
<?php

 $printer_name = "Daruma D800"; 
 $handle = printer_open($printer_name);
 printer_start_doc($handle, "Cupom Teste");
 printer_start_page($handle);
 $font = printer_create_font("Arial", 100, 100, 400, false, false, false, 0);
 printer_select_font($handle, $font);
 printer_draw_text($handle, 'Teste de Cupom.', 100, 400);
 printer_delete_font($font);
 printer_end_page($handle);
 printer_end_doc($handle);
 printer_close($handle);
 ?>
```

Comment: Quer imprimir no Servidor ou no navegador?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o servidor e o cliente sao na mesma maquina.

Comment: Se são na mesma máquina, não poderia resolver isto com um gerador de PDF ou HTML mesmo e depois `window.print` na página? Só por curiosidade que estou perguntando, de qualquer forma estou tentando baixar a dll compativel pra minha maquina pra testar e ver se consigo detectar o erro.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade se trata de um cupom não fiscal tipo um sistema de PDV entao eu achei mais produtivo imprimir direto na impressora sem confirmação. caso saiba de outra maneira de imprimir sem confirmação sera bem vinda

Comment: Verifique esta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195301/listar-impressoras-na-rede-com-php/195376#195376 acredito que possa lhe ajudar, na mesma é abordado tanto a instalação quanto a utilização.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A extensão php_printer é o meio padrão para se obter as impressoras conectadas ao servidor. Porém ela não vai identificar as impressoras de rede que não estejam configuradas no servidor pois não permite descoberta.

Se mesmo depois da instalação da extensão você não conseguiu tente seguir estes passos:

> **Obtendo impressoras sem a extensão, usando apenas linha de comando no windows:**
>
> Quando o PHP por sí só não consegue, podemos utilizar alguma interface de linha de comando, seja um script java ou python ou até mesmo um script php rodando com um php mais antigo. A técnica consiste em utilizar uma linha de comando e tratar a string do resultado.
>
> ```
> <?php
> //Função para tratar o retorno 
> function getPrinterProperty($key){
>     $str = shell_exec('wmic printer get '.$key.' /value');
>
>     $keyname = "$key=";
>     $validValues = [];
>     $fragments = explode(PHP_EOL,$str);
>     foreach($fragments as $fragment){
>         if($fragment == ""){
>             continue;
>         }
>         if (preg_match('/('.$keyname.')/i', $fragment)) {
>             array_push($validValues,str_replace($keyname,"",$fragment));
>         }
>     }
>     return $validValues;
> }
> //Esplanação dos commandos:
> // wmic /node:SERVER1 printer list status // Lista status das impressoras de um servidor remoto
> // wmic printer list status // Lista status das impressoras  do servidor local
> // wmic printer get // Obtem todas as propriedades da impressoa
> // wmic printer get <propriedade> /value //Lista uma propriedade no formato chave=valor do servidor remoto
> // wmic printer get <propriedade> /value //Lista uma propriedade no formato chave=valor do servidor local
>
> //Obtém algumas propriedades, nesse caso vou pegar só algumas
> $Name = getPrinterProperty("Name");
> $Description =  getPrinterProperty("Description");
> $Network = getPrinterProperty("Network");
> $Local = getPrinterProperty("Local");
> $PortName = getPrinterProperty("PortName");
> $Default = getPrinterProperty("Default");
> $Comment = getPrinterProperty("Comment");
>
> $Printers = [];
> foreach($Name as $i => $n){
>     $Printers[$i] = (object)[
>         "name" => $n,
>         "description" => $Description[$i],
>         "Portname" => $PortName[$i],
>         "isDefault" =>($Default[$i] == "TRUE")? true : false,
>         "isNetwork" => ($Network[$i] == "TRUE")? true : false,
>         "isLocal" =>($Local[$i] == "TRUE")? true : false,
>         "Comment" => $Comment[$i],
>     ];
> }
>
> var_dump($Printers);
>
> array(7) {
>   [0]=>
>   object(stdClass)#1 (7) {
>     ["name"]=>
>     string(29) "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
>     ["description"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Portname"]=>
>     string(11) "PORTPROMPT:"
>     ["isDefault"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isNetwork"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isLocal"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["Comment"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }
>   [1]=>
>   object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
>     ["name"]=>
>     string(22) "Microsoft Print to PDF"
>     ["description"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Portname"]=>
>     string(11) "PORTPROMPT:"
>     ["isDefault"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isNetwork"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isLocal"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["Comment"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }
>   [2]=>
>   object(stdClass)#3 (7) {
>     ["name"]=>
>     string(32) "HPC4C962 (HP Officejet Pro 8600)"
>     ["description"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Portname"]=>
>     string(45) "WSD-5277c4df-fd03-46fb-a957-1d8a0fd65b01.003c"
>     ["isDefault"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["isNetwork"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isLocal"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["Comment"]=>
>     string(30) "This is a web services printer"
>   }
>   [3]=>
>   object(stdClass)#4 (7) {
>     ["name"]=>
>     string(29) "HP Officejet Pro L7600 Series"
>     ["description"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Portname"]=>
>     string(12) "192.168.1.22"
>     ["isDefault"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isNetwork"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isLocal"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["Comment"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }
>   [4]=>
>   object(stdClass)#5 (7) {
>     ["name"]=>
>     string(24) "Foxit Reader PDF Printer"
>     ["description"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Portname"]=>
>     string(13) "FOXIT_Reader:"
>     ["isDefault"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isNetwork"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isLocal"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["Comment"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }
>   [5]=>
>   object(stdClass)#6 (7) {
>     ["name"]=>
>     string(3) "Fax"
>     ["description"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Portname"]=>
>     string(7) "SHRFAX:"
>     ["isDefault"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isNetwork"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isLocal"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["Comment"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }
>   [6]=>
>   object(stdClass)#7 (7) {
>     ["name"]=>
>     string(26) "Enviar para o OneNote 2013"
>     ["description"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>     ["Portname"]=>
>     string(4) "nul:"
>     ["isDefault"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isNetwork"]=>
>     bool(false)
>     ["isLocal"]=>
>     bool(true)
>     ["Comment"]=>
>     string(0) ""
>   }
> }
> ```

Agora você terá a lista de impressoras instaladas no sistema, então você pode utilizar um aplicativo que permita a executar via linha de comando, como o [Foxit Reader](https://help.foxitsoftware.com/?action=list&cate_id=92) e utilizar o seguinte comando:

> ```
> <?php 
>
> shell_exec('FoxitReader /t C:/Temp/file.txt "'.$Printers[0]->name.'"');
> ```

Estes procedimentos foram retirados da resposta [Listar impressoras na rede com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195301/listar-impressoras-na-rede-com-php/195376#195376) acredito que possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/132271)